# Convert char c = 'a' to int value = 10

Tags: c, hex

Having this piece of code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char c;
    int hex;
    ....
}
```

If `c` is 'a' I want `hex` to become 10. If `c` has 'f', `hex` should be 15. I know how to accomplish this task for integers (with `c - '0'` although this frowned upon) or with strings (using `sprintf` or `strtol`) but I don't know how to accomplish this simple task in general.

Comment: If c has '4', I would think you want the hex to store 4?  Or do you want binary: "100"?

Comment: Also, what is the range of c?  Do you want it to be a `char` or a `uchar`?  I'd think you want to go from 0 to 256, and it would be a `uchar`.

Comment: I fail to see how character 4 maps to Hex 10?  Hex 10 is (decimal)16.

Comment: Why would '4' be 10 in hex?

Comment: `hex = c - 'a' + 10;` before that check `c` is between `'a'` and `'f'`. Then support `'A'` to `'F'` and `'0'` to `'9'`.

Comment: And why does the title of the question not match the text of the question?

Comment: @abelenky: I suspect the original poster has typed `4` where they meant `a`.

Comment: Too much 1337 speak I guess. 4 -> a

Comment: Im sorry i edit my question because misprint

Comment: Arithmetic like `c-'0'` is perfectly acceptable. The issue is to recognize that C doesn't actually specify what character set is in use, or really even how many bits make up a character. That said, it is usually safe to use arithmetic like this to calculate distance from clear landmarks like '0' and 'A'. It can get tricky, however. Google EBCDIC and be thankful that the world turned away from that monster despite it being the product of IBM, then the single most powerful player in the world computer market.

Comment: @RBerteig: `c-'0'` is completely defined for `c` being a digit character. The C standard requires the digit characters to be consecutive in whatever character set is used.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes. But `c-'A'` is slightly more troublesome. EBCDIC does not have a consecutive alphabet: it is broken into three runs 'A'-'I', 'J'-'R', and 'S'-'Z'. At least the lower case is a constant offset from the upper, but their relative order is reversed from ASCII. That said, IIRC the choice of character set is an implementation definition, and I haven't personally seen an EBCDIC character in the wild in many years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean if that `c == 'a'`, then `hex = 10`.
Try this (assuming `c` is always in `['0'..'9']` union `['a'..'f']`:

```
hex = (c >= 'a' ? c - 'a' + 10 : c - '0');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    hex = c - '0';
else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
    hex = c - 'a' + 10;
else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
    hex = c - 'A' + 10;
else
    abort();
```

To catch bad input, you can add

```
if (hex >= base)  /* base would be e.g. 16 */
    abort();
```

or when `base` is fixed, you can limit the upper limit (e.g. `c <= 'f'` instead of `c <= 'z'`).  First method is more flexible and allows e.g. larger bases or converting octal numbers.

Comment: Since the OP mentions "hex", you probably wanted to restrict the comparisons to 'A' through 'F' not 'Z'. With that restriction, then it turns out that the resulting code is even portable to EBCDIC, the usual bane of arithmetic on character constants.

Comment: You answer is valid but i can choose one, i prefer the other answer because readability and compactness